# How to keep all Python Tkinter Windows on top to detect hover

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, menu, linux-mint

I'm making a clone of windows 98's start menu. I have the program almost finished I just need to get the buttons to open some programs. However for some reason the windows98 lookalike start menu keeps forcing me to start from the beginning in order to get through the menus. Each "tab" it's a docked borderless window because i was not sure how to make the program the shape it needed to be to appear over the operating system and over any open programs like how the old start menu should be. when i made it all one program it sat in the background when opened or it sat on top of the enter operating system making it really unrealistic. Start menu was only able to be placed on top as submenus when each window was created and destroyed using onenter and on exit when hovering over labels. so each tab is filled with labels that when the mouse hovers over it trades the image for the blue one and if it is a label that has a submenu like for example the programs part of the first start window it opens the next label (or in tkinter's world a new window)

as you can see in the video below the on hover events do not stay once the mouse leaves the window
(I created a transparent window in the background so that when the user clicks out of the start menu the program is aware of it and can handle closing the entire program to look like the start menu is just being closed)
the labels also do not turn blue when trying to backtrack to the previous window.

I am wishing for any kind soul here to assist me in solving these mysteries.

Here is a video showing the issue

https://youtu.be/KeK_qfV_X6s

I want to post the code for the program but the editor says that it is using too many characters to post it here.

I will send an example of how the new tabs are created and hope it's enough. I can send the script itself to someone who needs it.

'''code'''
def createProgramsTab():
global ProgramsTabWindow
ProgramsTabWindow = Toplevel(ClickToExitBackground)
ProgramsTabWindow.geometry("+205+270")
ProgramsTabWindow.geometry("150x147")
ProgramsTabWindow.configure(bg='#c0c0c0')
ProgramsTabWindow.deiconify()
EmptyProgramsTabLabelImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'assets/StartMenuPrograms.png'))
EmptyProgramsTabLabel = Label(ProgramsTabWindow, image=EmptyProgramsTabLabelImage)
EmptyProgramsTabLabel.photo = EmptyProgramsTabLabelImage
EmptyProgramsTabLabel.place(x=0,y=0)

```
    HomeBaseaccessoriesButtonImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'assets/startaccessoriesdefault.png'))
    HomeBaseaccessoriesButton = Button(ProgramsTabWindow, image=HomeBaseaccessoriesButtonImage, borderwidth=-10, highlightthickness=-10, relief=FLAT,bd=-10,bg="#c0c0c0")
    HomeBaseaccessoriesButton.photo = HomeBaseaccessoriesButtonImage
    HomeBaseaccessoriesButton.place(x=3,y=3, bordermode=INSIDE)
```

HomeBaseProgramsButtonImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'assets/startprogramsdefault.png'))
HomeBaseProgramsButton = Button(HomeBaseWindow, image=HomeBaseProgramsButtonImage, borderwidth=-10, highlightthickness=-10, relief=FLAT,bd=-10,bg="#c0c0c0")
HomeBaseProgramsButton.photo = HomeBaseProgramsButtonImage
HomeBaseProgramsButton.place(x=25,y=44, bordermode=INSIDE)

```
def onEnterPrograms(event):
    global HomeBaseProgramsButtonImage
    HomeBaseProgramsButtonImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'assets/startprogramsblue.png'))
    HomeBaseProgramsButton.config(image=HomeBaseProgramsButtonImage)
    HomeBaseProgramsButton.photo = HomeBaseProgramsButtonImage
    createProgramsTab()

    destroyfavoritesTab()
    destroysettingsTab()
    destroyaccessoriesTab()
    destroydevotionalservicesTab()
    destroyinitiationTabWindow()
    destroydocumentsTab()


def onLeavePrograms(event):
    global HomeBaseProgramsButtonImage
    HomeBaseProgramsButtonImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'assets/startprogramsdefault.png'))
    HomeBaseProgramsButton.config(image=HomeBaseProgramsButtonImage)
    HomeBaseProgramsButton.photo = HomeBaseProgramsButtonImage

HomeBaseProgramsButton.bind('<Enter>',  onEnterPrograms)
HomeBaseProgramsButton.bind('<Leave>',  onLeavePrograms)

HomeBaseWindow.attributes('-type', 'dock')
HomeBaseWindow.wait_visibility(HomeBaseWindow)
HomeBaseWindow.wm_attributes('-alpha', 1.0)
```

'''code'''

thank you again for any help

Billie

Comment: I somewhat figured out the issue. it is to do with the window being used as the transparent window in the background to make it possible for the tkinter program to detect a mouse click outside of the start menu. that transparent background had a "docked" window attribute. so I needed to change that to "toolbar" attribute to allow it to not force me out of the menu's that give hover color change and submenu access.

Comment: I made a mistake but the website will not let me change it for some reason. I meant to say that the window attribute needed to be set to "splash" not "toolbar" sorry for any confusion